# date time not iterable - error creating a list

Tags: python, list, datetime, iterable

I get the following error when I run this code

```
import datetime 

today = datetime.datetime.now()
print(today)

lst = []
lst = lst.extend(today)
lst = lst.extend(first_ok)
lst = lst.extend(second_ok) 
lst = lst.extend(all_payments)
```

where `first_ok` and `second_ok` are numeric variable

> TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable

Why a datetime is not iterable and cannot be placed in list? What to do about it?

Comment: Use `list.append`. `list.extend` extends with an entire iterable. Even better: `lst = [today, first_ok, second_ok, all_payments]`

Comment: Also no need to assign lst back to lst. just lst.append() is fine. lst = lst.append() would cause error in subsequent assignments.

Answer (score 2):

You are using extend, which needs an iterable. Datetime is not iterable but its a datetime object. You could use `append` instead

Answer (score 1):

When you `extend` a list you are adding the contents of a list inside another list. A `datetime` is not a list, so you cannot add the contents of a `datetime` into anything because there are no contents.

You are probably interested in append:

```
lst.append(today)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using append instead of extend.

Example:

```
import datetime 

today = datetime.datetime.now()
print(today)

lst = []
lst.append(today)
lst.append(first_ok)
lst.append(second_ok) 
lst.append(all_payments)
```